# Regex splitting string by space or " NOT " sequence (php)?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to split a string by spaces, unless there is the string " NOT ", in which case I would only want to split by the space before the "NOT", and not after the "NOT".
Example:

```
"cancer disease NOT brain NOT sickle"
```

should become:

```
["cancer", "disease", "NOT brain", "NOT sickle"]
```

Here is what I have so far, but it is incorrect:

```
$splitKeywordArr = preg_split('/[^(NOT)]( )/', "cancer disease NOT brain NOT sickle")
```

It results in:

```
["cance", "diseas", "NOT brai", "NOT sickle"]
```

I know why it is incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe `preg_match_all('~(?:\bNOT\s+)?\w+~', $string, $matches)`? See https://regex101.com/r/TANs0S/1

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
<?php

$text = "cancer disease NOT brain NOT sickle";
$pattern = "~NOT\s+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+~";

print_r(preg_split($pattern, $text));
?>
```

Which yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => cancer
    [1] => disease
    [2] => NOT brain
    [3] => NOT sickle
)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/FgM8mm).

Comment: I ended up using the "~NOT\s+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+~" pattern, and it worked well. Thank you!! @Jan

Comment: @kig: You may very well accept the answer then (grren tick on the left).

Answer (score 1):

You might also match optional repetitions of the word NOT followed by 1+ word characters in case the word occurs multiple times after each other.

```
(?:\bNOT\h+)*\w+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group
- `\bNOT\h+` A word boundary, match NOT and 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/442TYb/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/vfsEp)

```
$str = "cancer disease NOT brain NOT sickle";
preg_match_all('/(?:\bNOT\h+)*\w+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => cancer
    [1] => disease
    [2] => NOT brain
    [3] => NOT sickle
)
```